# How do I hold a signal high from one high pulse?

Tags: digital-logic, rf, control-system, computer-architecture, remote-control

Assuming I send a signal wirelessly to a receiver connected to a fan. if the receiver detects that a pulse is there, it switches on the fan. the fan should stay on until it detects another high pulse, then it should switch the fan off thereafter. 
How could I make this happen?

Comment: Tried a 1-bit counter?

Comment: This is not a high frequency control, right? ie, you are NOT using this as a PWM for speed control, this is just ON/OFF in the 'wall switch' sense, correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe a D Flip Flop? Tie the /Q to D and then the clock becomes your input. Each pulse (rising edge) should toggle the Q output pin state. That pin can then control a relay/FET/whatever to gate your fan.

Good luck!

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fE8TJB.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: Most FF's come with complementary outputs too!  you may not need an inverter.

Comment: this is good bcoz i have a bunch of dffs, why i handn't thought of it

Comment: @placeholder correct. I could not find that schematic symbol in CircuitLab unfortunately, but yes, this should be a single IC solution.

Answer (score 2):

If you use a latching relay on the fan end, it can latch on a high pulse, then "un-latch" on the next high pulse.  You will have to check the relay datasheet to be sure the length of the pulse is long enough to latch/unlatch, and that the voltage and current requirements are met for the relay coil latching.

Comment: +1: The other answers aren't wrong, but since the request is to control a fan, a relay is probably the simplest choice.

Comment: thankyou, i was also thinking of latching it but wasn't knowing how it would work, thanks